# What does 'imagined ecstasy' mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The song [Zedd - Addicted to Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqJiXLJs_Pg)'s lyrics contains a phrase 'Imagined ecstasy'.

Can anybody please explain it's meaning related to the song? 
Does it have any meaning outside the song? If it does, what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *Addicted to a Memory*.

There's nothing tricky in this.  'Ecstasy' is a state of euphoria, sublime happiness.  'Imagined' is created in the mind - not seen in reality.

So 'imagined ecstasy' is thinking that the situation (what *We are, we are*) is blissful when this is only in the couple's (or singer's) imagination - apparently based on how the relationship was in the past (*Holding on to what we used to be*).